# Is raw quinoa milk safe?

Tags: milk, quinoa

I've read about saponins in quinoa, some say you need to thoroughly rinse it while others say you don't need to since they have already been washed at processing plants.

Say I rinse it to make sure saponin's gone, would it be ok to just soak it overnight and blend it into milk without cooking?

Edit: Since posting the question I've also been researching on it. I can't find any resource saying if uncooked quinoa is poisonous or not. I'm not only referring to saponins but also starches and other compounds found in quinoa, saponin probably is the least of concerns. But I found this page that says you can just soak and blend quinoa into milk while many others recommend cooking it first.

[Yum Universe Non Dairy Milks](http://yumuniverse.com/plant-powerful-dairy-free-milk/)

Comment: I was having about an ounce of raw quinoa milk and it was ok but later I had about 2 or 3 ounces and it felt like mild food poisoning. It maybe just me but thought whoever reading this should know that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue with quinoa being soaked and rinsed is not a safety concern.  It is more a matter of flavor.

It is not dangerous.  Some people just find un-rinsed qinoa to be bitter.

In fact, for the most part, that bitter flavor is the majority of the interaction these saponins have with the body.

This article goes into some more detail:
[Questionable Quinoa: Perfect Plant Protein or Poison?](https://www.glutenfreegigi.com/questionable-quninoa-perfect-plant-protein-or-poison/)